# How do I create multiple Vue instances on the same .js file?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to add two `Vue.js` instance to the same `.js` file as follows :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#step1',
  data: {
    value1: '',
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#step2',
  data: {
    value2: '',
  }
})
```

I call these two instances in two separate web pages. But I'm getting a Vue warning such as `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #step1` not found or `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #step2` not found. 
Am I doing it wrong? or is there any way that I can concatenate the two instances together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you must design your code this way, you could test if the element is on that page first before instantiating the Vue instance:

```
if( document.getElementById("step1") ) {
    new Vue({
      el: '#step1',
      data: {
        value1: '',
      }
    })
}

if( document.getElementById("step2") ) {
    new Vue({
      el: '#step2',
      data: {
        value2: '',
      }
})
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything. If in the page 2 there is a #step1 element, everything will break. You can't make sure that all the ids in a view are unique across all views.

Comment: If you are the one writing the code, then you can certainly come up with a naming convention that will be a unique/dynamic value based on the route or page id

Comment: In my case, the code already exists. We have lots of views with simple, short ids that make sense in the context of each view. We can't manage to refactor all of that. Even if it were possible, this solution becomes heavy if you have lots of views: for each view, you will perform `getElementById` N times, being N the number of total views you have.

Comment: I would not have included all of your vue js code in one file that loads on every page.  I would dynamically load the js on each page that needs it.

Comment: Why not? That's the way big companies do it.